# At what point exactly is an object available for garbage collection?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I'm battling out of memory issues with my application and am trying to get my head around garbage collection.  If I have the following code:

```
public void someMethod() {
   MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
   myObject.doSomething();  //last use of myObject in this scope
   doAnotherThing();
   andEvenMoreThings();
}
```

So my question is, will `myObject` be available for garbage collection after `myObject.doSomething()` which is the last use of this object, or after the completion of `someMethod()` where it comes out of scope?  I.e. is the garbage collection smart enough to see that though a local variable is still in scope, it won't be used by the rest of the code?

Comment: I think you're using 'dereferenced' in the wrong context.

Comment: Just because the garbage collector sees that it isn't used doesn't man that it will choose to free it right away - you shouldn't be writing code that depends on the behavior of an unpredictable event ;) IF you have memory issues then you're probably keeping references to something by mistake :(

Comment: Hmm, thanks isah, I think you're right. I'll update the title to the question.

Comment: thanks deanWombourne, I do understand that. I am simply trying to learn more about how and when garbage collection works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Where it comes out of scope"

```
public void someMethod() {
   MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
   myObject.doSomething();  //last use of myObject in this scope
   myObject = null; //Now available for gc
   doAnotherThing();
   andEvenMoreThings();
}
```

Comment: it will happen at line 4 because you have explicitly dereferenced 
    myObject = null; //Now available for gc

Comment: in the question though it will end after the curly brace as there is no dereferencing..

Comment: You dont need to assign null to myObject. At the end of execution of someMethod(), myObject will be marked for gc anyway

Comment: Of course, it was only to highlight an eligible case inside a method.

Comment: yes and a wonderful example :) just clarification for other users who might drop here after googling :)

Comment: The eligble case is rarely used, unless you happen to know that the reference points to a large datastructure _and_ does not fall out of scope for a while.  Then the explicit setting to null is useful.

Answer (score 4):

The best thing you can do is to take your code put it in a loop with a delay and hook up a profiler to it.

If you are using a later version of Java then JVisualVm comes as standard.

If you are on windows and have JAVA_HOME set

> %JAVA_HOME%/bin/jvisualvm

This will launch a profiler and you can see what objects are being collected and what are not. In my opinion this is an essential part of being a programmer and its fun to find the memory leaks.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

Btw in later java 6, there is type of [escape analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_analysis#Optimizations) where JVM can find out that your instance of MyObject doesn't leave the method, so it even can place it entirely on stack and you will not need any GC for it at all.

Answer (score 3):

> So my question is, will myObject be available for garbage collection after myObject.doSomething() which is the last use of this object, or after the completion of someMethod() where it comes out of scope?

The former.

> I.e. is the garbage collection smart enough to see that though a local variable is still in scope, it won't be used by the rest of the code?

Scope is not visible to the GC which sees only registers, stacks, global variables and references from heap blocks to other heap blocks. So scope is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

After local scope is out. as object can be reused and can live in the local scope. ie. it is marked for gc. but not actually gc'ed .

Answer (score 2):

Code optimization will probably notice where the last *usage* of `myObject` is and make it available for garbage collection there, however technically it will be until the variable no longer refers to it (by being assigned to something else) or goes out of scope.

Comment: I don't think that's actually allowed by the JLS - or at least hotspot doesn't do this. .NET DOES actually allow exactly that which means we have [GC.KeepAlive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.keepalive.aspx) to avoid collecting objects (eg timers) with side effects earlier than we'd want. At least in Java I've never stumbled upon any mention of that which would surprise me.

Comment: Interesting.  By code optimization, do you mean JVM execution, GC execution or code compilation?